# How To Analyze Url To Add Appropriate Encoding On Appropriate Spots Of The Url?

Tags: php, urlencode

I need to parse user submitted urls before echoing their submitted urls on my page. need to parse the urls as I won't know what urls they will be submitting nor the structures of their urls.
On each submitted url, I need to add the key part of each query string on the $key array and the value part of each query string on the $value array. How to do this ?
Example, a user submits this url:
http://example.com/autos/cars/list.php?country=usa&min_price=5000

**FIRST STEP**
In this example, I need the $key array to be populated with:
**country,
min_price**

And, I need the $value array to be populated with:
**usa,
5000**

Then I need to echo each array's values.
How to do this ?

**SECOND STEP**
I need to auto add the appropriate encoding functions in the submitted url. So now I won't be echoing like this:

echo 'http://example.com/autos/cars/list.php?country=usa&min_price=5000';

But after parsing the url and after adding the appropriate encoding php functions in the correct spots of the url, I will be echoing like this:

echo rawurlencode('http://example.com/autos/cars/list.php') .'?country=' .urlencode('usa') .'&min_price=' .intval(5000);

Can you see, I auto added rawurlencode on the file path and urlencode on the query string's values and can you see I added intval where the query string's value was an INT ?
Well, I did all this additions manually here ofcourse to show you what I want php to do on auto. I really need to get php to auto analyze the url and auto add the rawurlencode(), urlencode() and intval() where appropriate. Add the 3 functions on the correct spots on the url.
How to do this ?

Once these two steps are achieved, then I can say a custom php function has been built that analyzes submitted urls and auto encodes the urls with the appropriate encoding functions (rawurlencode, urlencode, intval) on the correct spots on the url.

My Failed Attempt:

```
print_r(parse_url($url)); echo '<br>';

$keys = array(print_r(parse_url($url))); echo '<br>';

foreach($keys as $key=>$value)
{
    $key = array();
    $value = array();
    echo $key['0']; echo '<br>';
    echo $value['0']; echo '<br>';
}
```

Don't know how to proceed from this point onwards.

Comment: It is unclear what problem you are trying to actually solve. The `parse_url` function will give you everything that you need to know about the URL as a keyed array. For the querystring portion of the result, look at `parse_str`. It weirdly uses a ref parameter as the second (although someone might finally change that in 8.1) but that’ll get you key/values for the QS

Comment: @Chris Haas, Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction: parse_str().